# How can I set the crosshair in highcharts to a default position?

Tags: angular, position, export, highcharts

I’m using highcharts for a project with angular2. Currently I’m struggling with the following:

I have a synchronized chart with one x-axis and multiple y-axis – on mouseover I show a crosshair and display the y-axis-values in the legend.  (short demo-example of the [values in legend plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/10/Value-In-Legend))

If I load the chart, no value is displayed, as the crosshair appears after the first mouseover. 
What I am looking for is to have the crosshair displayed at all times, and if there is no mouseover it should stay at a default position (most current value displayed). Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

I already tried different approaches. The problem with plotlines is, that I can’t get the values in the legend to display the y-values/intersections of the plotline with the chart-lines.

Additionally I am using the export functionality of highcharts (offline) and am wondering if there is a way to export the chart with the legend AND the current values, instead of the initial empty ones, as the export function reloads the chart and as no crosshair is set, the legend values are empty in the exported file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the things you mentioned to achieve what you want. Using the part of the code from the plugin, you can set initial values for the legend, set a plotLine on load and remove it on mousemove.

Rendering initial values:

```
  function renderInitLegendValues() {
var chart = this,
    point = chart.series[0].data[2],
  point2 = chart.series[1].data[2],
  point3 = chart.series[2].data[2],
  hoverPoints = chart.hoverPoints = [point, point2, point3],
  legendOptions = chart.legend.options;

Highcharts.each(hoverPoints, function(point) {
  point.series.point = point;
  point.setState('hover');
});

Highcharts.each(chart.legend.allItems, function(item) {
  item.legendItem.attr({
    text: legendOptions.labelFormat ?
      Highcharts.format(legendOptions.labelFormat, item) : legendOptions.labelFormatter.call(item)
  });
});
chart.legend.render();
}
```

handling the plot line (first function will not let crosshair hides if the mouse move outside the plot area):

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
    return undefined;
};

function removeInitCrosshair(e) {
    var normE = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);

    if (chart.isInsidePlot(normE.chartX - chart.plotLeft, normE.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
       chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('initial-crosshair');
       $(this).off('mousemove', removeInitCrosshair);
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y58w4u9j/1/

As for exporting, you can define the plot line dynamically, set points' state on hover, and the legend's values, just before the exporting, so the image will include those changes.

Comment: Thank you! 
As I also asked the question in the highcharts-forum - here the link to another possible [solution](http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/set-crosshair-to-a-default-position-t36508/)